# How can I name my objects in Python?

Tags: python

I know this is a very simple question, but unfortunately I don't know enough to search effectively for an answer. Any answers or links to things I should already know would be greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to do is make an environment in Python where I have a bunch of turtles running around doing various things (it's basically like StarLogo from MIT).

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.xpos = float(x)
        self.ypos = float(y)
        self.head = 0.0

numTurtles = 4
for i in range(numTurtles):
    ...
MyTurtles = [...]
```

Each turtle has an x position, a y position, and a heading (in radians). All I want to do is create them and tell them where to stand (their x and y coordinates), and then put all the turtles into a list so that later I can tell the whole group to take a certain action.

I want to be able to change the number of turtles, otherwise I would just call them [a,b,c,d]. But I figure there has to be a better way.

Comment: They should be called Leonardo, Raphael, Michelangelo and Donatello.

Comment: As a stylistic aside: you should use snake_case for everything other than class names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the turtles to the list directly while executing the loop, for example

```
my_turtles = []
for i in range(num_turtles):
    x = ...
    y = ...
    h = ...
    my_turtles.append(Turtle(x, y, h))
```

It's often also possible to write this as a "list comprehension":

```
my_turtles = [Turtle(..., ..., ...) for i in range(num_turtles)]
```

Comment: Or even better a generator comprehension. 
`my_turtles = (Turtle(..., ..., ...) for i in range(num_turtles))`

Comment: +1: if you think you want to use dynamic variable names and then add all of those variables to a list, you're almost always wrong.

Comment: Mmmmm agreed, this is why python has dictionaries.

Comment: But then they will all be at the same location.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. I wasn't realizing they could just be named my_turtles[0], my_turtles[1], etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to be accessible by some unique name, but avoid having a billion variables, you could always store them in a `dict`ionary.

```
{ "Norma": Turtle(1, 2), "Kyle": Turtle(3, 4) }
```

You can modify a dictionary after it's been created, appending and deleting as you like.

```
turtles["Norma"] = Turtle(30, 40) # we just replaced Norma
turtles["Rackham"] = Turtle(0, 1) # a new turtle added.
```

There are a number of ways to generate such a dictionary, should you not want to make it by hand.

Using `zip` we can take two iterables, and make pairs out of the consecutive values:

```
zip(["Norma", "Rackham"], [Turtle(1, 2), Turtle(0, 1)])
```

The result is an interable returning tuples (dimension is decided by amount of arguments given to zip.)

Handily enough, the dictionary constructor can take such a list:

```
dict(zip(["Norma", "Rackham"], [Turtle(1, 2), Turtle(0, 1)]))
```

Et voilá. A dictionary.

You can also use a dictionary expression (availability depends on Python version):

```
{ name: turtle for name, turtle in zip(names, turtles) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Turtle(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,name):
        self.xpos = float(x)
        self.ypos = float(y)
        self.head = 0.0
        self.name = name

my_turtles = []
for name, i in zip(xrange(num_turtles), names):
    x = ...
    y = ...
    h = ...
    my_turtles.append(Turtle(x, y, h, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.xpos = float(x)
        self.ypos = float(y)
        self.head = 0.0
    def certain_action():
        # Do action

numTurtles = 4
MyTurtles = []
# Need to set x and y
for i in range(numTurtles):
    MyTurtles.append(Turtle(x,y))

for t in MyTurtles:
    t.certain_action()
```